# Failing to click the Intellij variable watch popup window, because it gets closed too fast.

Tags: intellij-idea

When I move the mouse over a variable while debugging a java program inside IntelliJ a variable watch popup window is displayed. The window suggests to click it to expand the view, but the moment I move the mouse the popup is closed! I have never succeeded in expanding the view inside such a popup watch window.

Is there any setting to let the popup window be a bit more sticky?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd> **on the variable** to get a sticky pop-up. Please also [vote for the related issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-63112).

This shortcut is defined in the **Keymap** (`Main menu` | `Run` | **Quick Evaluate Expression**):

[image: Quick Evaluate Expression]

Comment: How? The popup just closes even before I get to move the mouse over the "click here to view ..."

Comment: Alt+Click on the variable, not on the pop-up. Pop-up is just a hint with incorrect wording (see the linked issue).

Comment: Alt+Click navigates to the respective symbol, be it variable or method. Do you mean I should cancel this key mapping?

Comment: OS/keymap? I tested on Windows with the default keymap. It doesn't work on Mac, will update the issue.

Comment: No, Windows 7. And I am wrong - it does not navigate anywhere, but it changes the mouse cursor to a pointing finger and underlines part or all of the statement, as if it was a hyperlink. But clicking it does nothing.

Comment: OK, it was Alt+F9 on my machine, probably because I am working with the Visual Studio keymap. Changed to Alt+click and it works now. Thanks. However, the bug remains that the popup closes immediately as the mouse is moved not letting to click the designated area.

Comment: The bug is not with the pop-up, but with the hint. It should say that you need to alt+click on the variable. Popup itself is not designed to be clicked on.

Comment: Oh, I see. I thought it was like the Eclipse popups, which upgrade to first class windows when clicked, which is very convenient in case of a watch window.